# Group elements in list of lists based on elements in another list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have two list of lists:

`A = [['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['c'], ['e'], ['g', 'h']]` and

`B = [['a'], ['c', 'd'], ['b', 'e'], ['g', 'h']]`.

How can I reorder elements in B such that each sublist in B contains same groups of elements in the sublists in A while keeping same length for B?

i.e, B can becomes

`[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e'], ['g', 'h']]`

Sublists in B that have all their elements in a sublist in A e.g `['g', 'h']`, should be left unchanged.
Sublists in B werein all elements are single-element sublists in A e.g `['c', 'd']` should be left unchanged as well.

Comment: it is not really clear for me what you are trying to accomplish. can you make it more clear please ?

Comment: I want to change the order of elements in B when all elements in any given sublist in B are not in the same sublist in A. You can view A as a condition that should be fulfilled by B. Does this help clarify it?

Comment: What you just wrote contradicts [c, d] staying together. So it's no more clear than before.

Comment: [c,d] can stay together because they are single-element sublists without pairs. Any single-element sublist in A can be grouped together in B.

Comment: can there be duplicate items in the lists ? two `a`s for example.

Comment: No duplicates. Both list of lists contain distinct elements across all sublists

Comment: B can also equal [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'e'], ['d'], ['g', 'h']]. or [['a', 'b'], ['d', 'e'], ['c'], ['g', 'h']]. or [['a', 'b'], ['e'], ['c', 'd'], ['g', 'h']]. because ['c'], ['d'] and ['e'] in A are single-element sublists, so they can be grouped together in B

Comment: What if you always return `B = [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]]` `B = A` would that be allowed ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I need them in groups (separate sublists)

Comment: I just updated the question to reflect some of the comments. To provide more clarity

Comment: @donmoy what do you think of starting from A and merging elements until it's length becomes the same as B and if it has lower number you append empty lists to it instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252598/discussion-between-donmoy-and-zaki98).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be taking into account anything in B apart from the number of sublists.  If I understand correctly, you only need to prevent breaking up of groups from A while merging them into the number of sublists of B.

Here's a recursive function I believe could do the job for you:

```
def combine(lists,count):
    if len(lists)<count: return # no empty lists
    if count == 1:
        yield[ [n for s in lists for n in s] ]
        return
    first = []
    for i,s in enumerate(lists):
        first.extend(s)
        for rest in combine(lists[i+1:],count-1):
            yield [first]+rest
```

output:

```
A = [['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['c'], ['e'], ['g', 'h']]

B = [['a'], ['c', 'd'], ['b', 'e'], ['g', 'h']]

for r in combine(A,len(B)): print(r)

[['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['c'], ['e', 'g', 'h']]
[['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['c', 'e'], ['g', 'h']]
[['a', 'b'], ['d', 'c'], ['e'], ['g', 'h']]
[['a', 'b', 'd'], ['c'], ['e'], ['g', 'h']]
```

**[Edit]**

Based on comments below, if the rule can be expressed as:

- no groups of A shall be broken up and
- only groups of B that are entirely formed of single item groups in A can be broken up

You could use sets to make the combination/exclusions easier to deal with.  First identify the unbreakable groups in A and B and place these fixed groups in the result.  Then add the remaining elements to the smallest group.

```
def combine(A,B):
    fixedB  = [b for b in map(set,B)
              if len(b)>1 and all([c] in A for c in b)]
    fixedA  = [a for a in map(set,A) if len(a)>1]
    result  = fixedA+fixedB
    result += [set() for _ in range(len(B)-len(result))]
    rest    = set().union(*A)-set().union(*result)
    for r in rest:
        min(result,key=len).add(r)
    return list(map(list,result))
```

output:

```
A = [['a', 'b'], ['d'], ['c'], ['e'], ['g', 'h']]

B = [['a'], ['c', 'd'], ['b', 'e'], ['g', 'h']]
    
print(combine(A,B))

[['a', 'b'], ['g', 'h'], ['c', 'd'], ['e']]
```

This will give you one solution.  To get more alternatives, you would probably need to make this a generator and work with permutations and possibly recursion to place the mobile items.

There are a few more rules to think of and express:

- What to do when there are more fixed groups than available slots in B. (is that an error or should there be some larger merging)
- Can there be overlaping fixed groups between A and B (e.g. ['a','b'] in A and ['b','c'] in B), if so, how should that be processed
- Can there be larger than 2-item groups in A or B and, if so, should a smaller A group entirely contained in a B group allow breaking up of the rest of the B group or not ?
- probably more edge cases that I haven't thought of

Comment: This is almost what I want but can the solution be modified so that I always get the third output. I should have be more clearer in the question.

Sublists in B that have all their elements in a sublist in A e.g ['g', 'h'], should be left unchanged. Sublists in B werein all elements are single-element sublists in A e.g ['c', 'd'] should be left unchanged as well.

This is the result I want: [['a', 'b'], ['d', 'c'], ['e'], ['g', 'h']]

Comment: In the example given in your question, it will be impossible to combine the sublist without breaking a group in A or B.  The expected result in your comment above, breaks ['b','e'].  Would it be correct to express the rule as 1) no groups of A shall be broken up and 2) only groups of B that are formed of smaller groups of A can be broken up ? It would also help to indicate that all elements are distinct and present in both A and B

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works for me. I tried it with 3-item gtoups and it still works. Just accepted your answer and thank for your help again.